# Want To Copy Certain Fields From Previous Entry To New Fragment

Tags: google-app-maker

**Short Version:** I want to have my Copy button in a table to be able to grab the values from an existing entry and populate those into a "Create Entry" Page Fragment. This way users don't have to reenter all the data when making a new entry.

---

**Long Version:**

I have two buttons added the rows in my table: Edit and Copy.

[image]

The Edit Button uses the following code to grab the information from that specific row and uses the Fragment to edit the entry.

```
widget.datasource.saveChanges();
app.datasources.SystemOrders.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key);
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.SystemOrders_Edit);
```

The Copy button is currently using the following code to duplicate the entry and automatically create it.

```
//Allows for copying table/row
var rowDataSource = widget.datasource;
var listDatasource = app.datasources.SystemOrders_HideComplete;
var createDataSource = listDatasource.modes.create;

widget.datasource.saveChanges();

// Enter fields you want to duplicate below
createDataSource.item.ProjectName = rowDataSource.item.ShowName;
createDataSource.item.DeliveryInfo = rowDataSource.item.DeliveryInfo;
createDataSource.item.SOB = rowDataSource.item.SOB;
createDataSource.item.DeliveryDate = rowDataSource.item.DeliveryDate;
createDataSource.item.Company = rowDataSource.item.Company;
createDataSource.item.Location = rowDataSource.item.Location;
 createDataSource.item.AdditionalPeripherals = rowDataSource.item.AdditionalPeripherals;
createDataSource.item.Notes = rowDataSource.item.Notes;
createDataSource.createItem();
```

I would like to change this behavior so that the Copy button grab the values from those specific fields, however instead of doing a createDataSource/createItem(); I want it to place those values into a Page Fragment (ex: SystemOrders_Add) that has the corresponding fields.

This way the user can click "Copy" and the SystemOrders_Add Fragment appears with pre-populated values.

I want to make sure these values are only in the Page Fragment and do not get commited until the user presses the Submit button.

```
newSOEmailMessage(widget);
widget.datasource.createItem();
app.closeDialog();
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Pavel and Wilmar. The solution that worked for me is listed below:

```
//Allows for copying table/row
var rowDataSource = widget.datasource;
var listDatasource = app.datasources.SystemOrders_HideComplete;
var createDataSource = listDatasource.modes.create;

widget.datasource.saveChanges();

// Enter fields you want to duplicate below
createDataSource.item.ShowName = rowDataSource.item.ShowName;
createDataSource.item.DeliveryInfo = rowDataSource.item.DeliveryInfo;
createDataSource.item.SOB = rowDataSource.item.SOB;
createDataSource.item.Notes = rowDataSource.item.Notes;

app.datasources.SystemOrders.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key);

app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.SystemOrders_Add);
```

Answer (score 1):

one way you can accomplish this is by passing the data to Custom Properties defined in your Page Fragment and then you can place those properties to the corresponding fields. I recommend you also check this article https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/viewfragments#use_custom_properties_to_customize_page_fragments

First you need to create the Custom Properties inside your Page Fragment. Then in your Copy button onClick event you can use something like this to save the row data from your table to the Custom Properties:

```
var rowDataSource = widget.datasource.item._key;
app.datasources.SystemOrders.selectKey(rowDataSource);

var projectName = app.datasources.SystemOrders.item.project_name;
var deliveryInfo = app.datasources.SystemOrders.item.delivery_info;
//...
app.pageFragments.SystemOrders_Edit.properties.ProjectName = projectName;
app.pageFragments.SystemOrders_Edit.properties.DeliveryInfo = deliveryInfo;
//...
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.SystemOrders_Edit);
```

Assuming you have a form inside your Page Fragment, you can bind the value of each field with custom properties. Binding will ensure that the data is pre-populated. This can be done for each field via the Property Editor and the binding should look like this: @properties.ProjectName

Inside your Submit button onClick event you can use something like this to create a new item in the datasource using the values available in each field.

```
var projectName = widget.root.descendants.Field1.value;
var deliveryInfo = widget.root.descendants.Field2.value;
//...

var myDatasource = app.datasources.SystemOrders_HideComplete;
var myCreateDatasource = myDatasource.modes.create;
var draft = myDatasource.modes.create.item;

   draft.project_name = projectName;
   draft.delivery_info = deliveryInfo;
   //...

   // Create the new item
   myCreateDatasource.createItem();

app.closeDialog();
```

You can set properties back to null once item is created (maybe onDetach) like this:
app.pageFragments.SystemOrders_Edit.properties.ProjectName = null;

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that removing this line from the Copy Button click handler will make a trick(of course, if your page fragment is bound to ds.modes.create.item):

```js
createDataSource.createItem();
```

In case, you are using Manual save mode and you are trying to reuse Page Fragment without overriding datasource... you need create new items using different approach:

```js
// Copy Button click handler
var source = widget.datasource.item;
var listDatasource = app.datasources.SystemOrders_HideComplete;

// This line will add new item to the list datasource
// without saving it to database.
listDatasource.createItem();
var target = listDatasource.item;

// Enter fields you want to duplicate below
target.Field1 = source.Field1;
target.Field2 = source.Field1;
...

// Show fragment (assuming it is bound to listDatasource.item)
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.EditItemFragment);


// -----------
// Page Fragment's Submit Button click handler
...
listDatasource.saveChanges(function() {
  // TODO: handle successful save
});
```

Comment: Tried the option you listed above, but it didn't seem to work. I think that is because that datasource for my fragment was SystemOrders_HideComplete (create). Anyhow, removing the createDataSource.createItem(); option from the previous text worked! Thank you for your help.